# Extension of an integral formula on an open complex subset

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

Using the integral of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2418804/evaluate-the-integral-int-mathbbr-frace-gamma-x1exdx/2418889?noredirect=1#comment4995502_2418889), we can conclude easily that 
for $x >0$ and $1>r>0,$ we have 
$$x^{r-1} = \frac{\sin(\pi r)}{\pi} \int_0^\infty \frac{s^{r-1}}{s+x}ds,$$
I wonder whether we can extend the above formula on the subset 
$$\Gamma := \{z\in \mathbb{C}; Re(z) >0\},$$
or maybe in another subset contained in $\Gamma.$

The "simple" way to go is: let $z\in \Gamma,$ then we have $|z|>0$ and 
$$|z|^{r-1} = \frac{\sin(\pi r)}{\pi} \int_0^\infty \frac{s^{r-1}}{s+|z|}ds.$$
on the other hand,

$$z^{r-1} := |z|^{r-1}e^{i(r-1)Arg(z)} = \frac{\sin(\pi r)}{\pi} \int_0^\infty \frac{s^{r-1}e^{i(r-1)Arg(z)}}{s+|z|}ds.$$
I don't see why the term inside the integral must be $\frac{s^{r-1}}{s+z}.$

Maybe this is not the best way to go ...

Thank you for any hint.

Comment: What do you know about analytic functions, analytic continuation ?

Comment: Some basic information.  in the case of this question the subset $(0,+\infty)$ is not  open in $\mathbb{C}$ !

Answer (score 1):

Let $U=\{z\in \mathbb{C}; z\not \in ]-\infty,0]\}$. For $z\in U$, $z=|z|\exp(i\theta)$, $-\pi<\theta<+\pi$, we put $\log z=\log |z|+i\theta$, this function is analytic in $U$ (this is the "principal determination of the logarithm"). The function $z\to F(z)= \frac{\sin(\pi r)}{\pi}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{s^{r-1}}{z+s}ds$ is also analytic in $U$. Then as $\exp((r-1)\log z)-F(z)$ is analytic in the connected open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{C}$, and zero on $]0,+\infty[$, it is $0$ on $U$, and your formula is valid on $U$.

Comment: @reuns Sorry, but your comment is not clear for me...Can you explain ? thanks in advance .

Comment: In fact the remark concerns the last line in your argument; you wrote: .... and zero on $(0, +\infty).$ My question is: shouldn't the function $\exp((r-1)\log(z)) -F(z)$ be zero on some open subset of $U$ to conclude ?

Comment: Let $g$ a non zero analytic function on $V$, open connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Then the zeros of $g$ are isolated in $V$, ie if $g(z_0)=0$, then $g$ is non zero for $z\in V$, $z\not =z_0$ close to $z_0$. Here a zero $x\in ]0,+\infty[$ is not isolated, so the function has to be $0$ on $U$.

Comment: OK you are right. I was always thinking of the analytic continuation; If two analytic functions $f:A \to \mathbb{C}$ and $F: B \to \mathbb{C},$ with $A, B$ are two open subsets in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $A\subset B$  and $f=F$ on U, then $F$ is an analytic continuation on the larger subset $B$

Comment: There are maybe two points to be clear: is the function (implicitly the integral) $z\mapsto F(z)$ well defined on $U$ ? Shouldn't  we take  $Re(z)$ to be positive ? Could you please give more details about the analyticity of $F$ on its definition domain?

Comment: Put $z=x+iy\in U$. Then, for all $s\in [0,+\infty[$, we have $[z+s|=\sqrt{(x+s)^2+y^2}>0$ (as if it is zero, we have $y=0$ and $x=-s\leq 0$). As $|s+z|\sim s$ if $s\to +\infty$, the integral is (absolutely) convergent. For the analyticity, see any course on analytic functions.